# Swift 4 OutputStream produces more output than input

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, stream

I have been attempting to use streams in swift to interface with a java socket server (I don't believe the java server is my problem) but when I attempt to write with an OutputStream my string includes a bunch of extra garbage that was not in my original string

The code currently looks like this:

```
var maxWriteLength = 4096
func sendMessage(msg: String) {
    let encodedDataArray = [UInt8](msg.utf8)
    outputStream.write(encodedDataArray, maxLength: maxWriteLength)
}
```

However when I give it an input of "hi" it returns an ouput of:

> Echo: hi���8B��,r`ؾ�؇��allowCloudBackup؇��allowAppInstallation؇��safariForceFraudWarning�&��q���`ޙTh�C��=wthread��&��q�������������`���8$��N�`�8$�`��0'}``��#�
>   Echo: �'��q����������p�g`�iYh�C���iYh�C��
>   Echo: D�`@D�`8״
>   Echo: pV���؇��requireAlphanumeric؇��allowCellularHDUploadsInternational-Key_2��

and much much more

I have seen other posts suggesting that you should use encodedDataArray.count instead of a maxWriteLength however when I have used this the OutputStream will not write anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `encodedDataArray.count` is the right solution. You should better consider why _the OutputStream will not write anything_. How have your checked it? **_I don't believe the java server is my problem_** you should better not have too strong presumption when something weird is happening.

Answer (score 0):

For future people who struggle with this it was indeed the way the server was handling messages (I went back to check it). The problem was that I was using Scanner.nextLine() and had no \n inside of the swift portion of my code. If you are using an array make sure that you add + "\n" to your string before it is made into an array otherwise the bytes for \n will not be written. The final code looked like this:

```
func sendMessage(msg: String) {
    var finalMsg = msg + "\n"
    let encodedDataArray = [UInt8](finalMsg.utf8)
    outputStream.write(encodedDataArray, maxLength: encodedDataArray.count)
}
```